# "Unable to attach to the tab" in Firefox's App Manager

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

I get this alert sometimes in my Firefox v33.0.3 when I click on Debug in App Manager, while testing a Firefox OS app. And whenever it appears, it doesnt let me see the debug section.

[image]

How do I resolve this?

**EDIT**
This error occurs when I connect the Alcatel Flame device running Firefox OS 2.0 to the Windows 7 machine.

**Steps to reproduce the problem:**

1. Connect the phone to the Windows machine using the cable.
2. Connect the phone to Firefox Desktop through the App Manager.
3. Install any app.
4. Click 'Debug'.

Comment: Are you attaching to the simulator or a phone?  What version of Firefox OS are you attaching to?

Comment: @JasonWeathersby It happens when I attach it to the phone - Alcatel Flame running Firefox OS 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a connection error, you'll have to mention the steps you went through in order for us to repeat them and figure out why there is a connection issue.